# CSS/React issue

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styling

I built page using react. All components are nice and working. Issue that I have is that all my body tags has width 100%, but only ganeral background picture that I put in body comes out of range.
this is CSS :

```
body {
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: var(--white);
  background-image: url('./assests/gallery/4bg (1).jpg');
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

My app component nesting next:

```
<comp1/>
<comp2/>
<comp3/>
```

and so on.
Each component is lined up with width 100% and looking good. Only that background is jumping out. When I have picture its just out of body and I have option to scroll left and right(I dont want to have such option) I need the page to be one. When there is no background picture, its just extra white space on the right side of the each component thru the page.
This is production demo to show what I mean: https://glass-commercial-template.vercel.app/
when you scrioll to the right, you will see the problem.

Even when I try to put width 100% or any other chnages it still stays same. I did try to chnage background-size and all that properties, but it didnt help.
I tried to chnage html and still same.
I tried to debug in all posible ways, but now I am cluless.

Answer (score 0):

your `.work-caption` has a transform which extends the window width.

you can debug it yourself by putting following css into your page:

```
* {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .1);
}
```

[image: live screenshot with background color on all elements applied]